# SQL : How to insert column with value TYPE

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to insert a column with value TYPE I get below error

`SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TYPE": invalid identifier` since TYPE is reserved keyword.

But, I see that this column already has values as TYPE. How someone could have inserted it? If I want to badly insert column value as TYPE is there any way?

This is my insert statement - `insert into processtable values(LB,Type,DI,Y,1,I,006,1,Type);`

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Well is there any specific reason to use that identifier name?? I think an identifier which has the same name with reserved word can make people confused.

Comment: use double quotes: "TYPE"

Answer (score 0):

You encountered a reserved word, so **you need double-quoting**:

```
insert into customers (1, "TABLE");
```

Notice that it is not:

```
insert into customers (1, 'TABLE');
```

as usual.

Comment: When I run SELECT statement, I should use "doubleqoutes"  or 'singleqoutes' right?

Comment: String literals need single quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers. Both statements are invalid because they are missing the `values` clause.

Comment: Just use double-quotes when you deal with reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

For select operation you can use `[]`(square brackets)

To insert successfully use backticks ( ` ) or double quotes (")

```
insert into processtable values(LB,'Type',DI,Y,1,I,006,1,'Type');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string values in single quotes like

```
insert into processtable values('LB','Type','DI','Y','1','I','006',1,'Type');
```

Answer (score 0):

> insert into processtable values(LB,Type,DI,Y,1,I,006,1,Type);

The `values` part lists the values (pun intended) to be stored in the new row. String values need to be put into single quotes:

```
insert into processtable values('LB','Type','DI','Y',1,'I','006',1,'Type');
```

Numbers must not be quoted.

For more details please read the section ["Literals"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00217) in the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL" in the Oracle manual. In fact I strongly suggest you read the complete chapter.

> *The terms literal and constant value are synonymous and refer to a fixed data value. For example, `'JACK'`, `'BLUE ISLAND'`, and `'101'` are all character literals; `5001` is a numeric literal. Character literals are enclosed in single quotation marks so that Oracle can distinguish them from schema object names.*

---

It is also good coding style to explicitly list the columns in the insert statement:

```
insert into processtable 
  (col1,  col2,  col3, col4, col5, col6, col7,  col8, col9)
values 
  ('LB', 'Type', 'DI', 'Y',  1,    'I',  '006', 1,    'Type');
```

Comment: _Numbers must not be quoted_.? I used to give quotes to numbers also. I'm able to insert succesfully.is there any problem giving quotes to numbers?(Not relevant to this question)

Comment: @Crazy2crack If you use single quotes for numbers, then Oracle (or any other DBMS) is doing an _implicit_ data type conversion which might or might not work the way you want it. Used in a where clause e.g. `where foo = '42'` this might result in the DBMS not using an index on the column. It's better to always use the correct literal type to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

for the best insertion  u can use this as follow and get succesfull insert:-

insert into processtable values('LB','Type','DI','Y',1,'I',006,1,'Type')

Answer (score -1):

type is a keyword in SQL.
If you want to ignore that it is a keyword and insert this anyway you can surround type in square brackets:

```
create table my_table as ([type] varchar(127))
```

Comment: `[type]` is an invalid identifier in (standard) SQL . To use reserved words you need to use double quotes `"TYPE"`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To be clear - square brackets works in some flavours of SQL including Microsoft's t-sql. But the double quotation marks solution seems to be standard.

Comment: The double quotes **are** defined in the SQL standard (the square brackets will **not** work in Oracle - which this question is about)